# How can i ignore blank cells while some cells contain zero value

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a sheet called systemdata which provides values to another sheet but some cells in the systemdata sheet have Zero and some are empty, any one with away which can help me show the Zero value in the other sheet and ignore the empty cell.

here is the code have tried

```
=IF((SYSTEMDATA!R2)="","",IF((SYSTEMDATA!R2)=0,0,IF(AND((SYSTEMDATA!R2)<>0,(SYSTEMDATA!R2)<>""),SYSTEMDATA!R2)))
```

[image]

Comment: Check your caps key so you don't SHOUT at us.

Comment: need more details, how do you want the result sheet to look like?

Comment: i want the result sheet to look like the systemdata sheet because am picking specific data from the systemdata sheet

Comment: Like if you see the IN column i want it to have 565 and the blank cell and the same with the rest

Comment: Just: `=IF(SYSTEMDATA!R2="","",SYSTEMDATA!R2)` would do it.

Comment: but i want it to show the Zero value rather than taking the cell that contains zero as an empty cell